# Can't use Excel header name in every statement

Tags: c#, excel, oledbdatareader

I use `OleDbDataReader` to read values from an Excel sheet.

When I collect the result into variables, sometimes I can use the Excel column header, and sometimes I can not.

When it's a date field, I need to refer to the column number.

```
string description = (string)reader["Description"];
var bsd = reader.GetDateTime(2);
var bfd = reader.GetDateTime(3);
string wc = (string)reader["Main WorkCtr"];
```

[image]

How do I use column header for the date variables?

If I change the code to `reader["Bas. start date"]` I get an error when running that looks like this:

[image]

It's not spelled wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by _can not_? You get an error exception? On which code? What is the type of `Main WorkCtr` and `Description` columns? Show your work also.

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to type it when using reader.GetDateTime(2);
When I type reader.GetDateTime("Bas. start date"); I get this errormessage in the compiler: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetDateTime(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What are the type of your all columns?

Comment: It fails before compiling since reader.GetDateTime("Bas. start date") is not the right way to type it. Error named in comment above.

Comment: @Skram Because all `GetXXX` methods take `int` parameter as a zero-based column number.

Comment: Ok.Then maybe I should collect the date in a different way, since the header might change position.

Comment: `reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Bas. start date"))`